# Jquery input selector by ID

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to insert a value into an input field with no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.press').on('keyup', function () {
        $("input[id=result]").html(parseInt($('#inputone').val()) * parseInt($('#inputtwo').val()));
    });
});


<form id="myform">
    <input class="press" id="inputone" type="text"></input>
    <input class="press" id="inputtwo" type="text"></input>
    <input class="press" id="result" type="text"></input>
</form>
<div id="notform"></div>
```

No matter what I try as the selector I can't get it to input into the field ID result. I've tried `#result`, `#myform #result`, `:input#result`, `"input[id=result]"` and nada. But when I put it in the div outside the form it's fine

http://jsfiddle.net/VfqRb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the value of an input element, you need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) not [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#result").val(parseInt(($('#inputone').val()) || 0) * (parseInt($('#inputtwo').val()) || 0));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qk3Au/)

Comment: Bloody hell. I got so hung up on the selector I missed that. Thanks Arun.

Comment: @MichaelN it such cases some minor debugging steps will help you resolve the problem like add a logging statement to see what is the result of the selector like `console.log($('#result'), $('#result').length)` in the event handler... in browser console if it prints the element and 1 then the selector is right..

Comment: @ArunPJohny code snippet is fine but seems your fiddle link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Arun's answer is correct. However, I'd also suggest that you do some validation before setting the value. The user may try to type some letters into that box, or multiply by 0 (which you may not care about, but still).

If nothing else, I suggest something along the lines of:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.press').on('keyup', function () {

      if ( ($('#inputone').val().length > 0) && ($('#inputtwo').val().length > 0) ) {


               var firstInput = parseInt($('#inputone').val());
               var secondInput = parseInt($('#inputtwo').val());

               if (!isNaN(firstInput) && !isNaN(secondInput) ) 
               {

                     $("#result").val(firstInput * secondInput);

               }

               else

               {
                      alert("Eh, how about some real numbers?")
               }

     }

});

});
```

Comment: I used input type="number" on my form, but some better validaiton could be used as this then just throws out a NaN

Comment: Point made, Arun. It will still return it as the infamous NaN. So one should account for that. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VCXKx/